# UICollectionView scroll is not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

Hi i am making iOS application where i am using UICollectionView to show date and time and at the bottom i am showing xib view but problem is when i am using addSubview(self.bottomSheetVC.view) UICollectionView scroll view is not working.

```
 func addBottomVC() {
    bottomSheetVC = BottomSheetVC()
    self.bottomSheetVC.delegate = self
        self.view.willRemoveSubview(self.bottomSheetVC.view)
        let height = self.view.frame.size.height
        let width  = self.view.frame.width
        self.bottomSheetVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.maxY - height, width: width, height:height)
        self.addChildViewController(self.bottomSheetVC)
        self.view.addSubview(self.bottomSheetVC.view)
        self.bottomSheetVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

As soon I remove `self.view.addSubview(self.bottomSheetVC.view)` it is working smoothly but the bottom view isn't displayed after removing this.

Comment: as soon i am removing  self.view.addSubview(self.bottomSheetVC.view) it working smooth but the bottom view cant show after remove this.

Comment: All necessary information should be in the question instead of comments. In the future you should [edit] your original post when new information arise instead of adding a comment. For now, I've edited the comment into your question.

Comment: Why are you calling `self.view.willRemoveSubview(self.bottomSheetVC.view)` when you're actually adding that later and not removing it? You shouldn't call `willRemoveSubview`.

Comment: BottomSheetVC is being added as a child view controller and is the same size as the parent. Which ViewController has the collectionView?